# Error after successfully importing sql file

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Please help me as soon as possible.
My problem is, I have successfully uploaded website and its database i.e. its sql file but still it is showing database error connection. My website is in wordpress. Please help me. It is very important.

I have heard that there are some changes which should be done in database in phpmyadmin panel. Is this so?
than tell me what are the changes.??

Comment: You need to change the database connection credentials in `wp-config.php` to the correct values

Comment: As you said __I have heard that there are some changes__, then why not you tried that changes? Have you tried google?

Answer (score 0):

You had to change your configuration related wp-config.php file where your database , username and password has been changed in this file .

```
define('DB_NAME', 'yourdatabsename');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'yourusername');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'yourpassword');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'yourhostname');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the required database credential changes in `wp-config.php` file present in the root directory of Wordpress.

After then you might need to change the `home` and `siteurl` values to the domain name of the newly uploaded website in `wp_options`  table.

Answer (score 0):

You should take care of following things when you setup you wordpress website from localhost to live server.

1. Change database settings from wordpress/wp-config.php
2. Update `siteurl` from wp-options table
3. Update `guid` and if you have url in your posts or pages content then you have to update the `post_content` column also from wp-posts table.

Take a look on this article that help you to acheive that. 
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/